# Error 500 when unknown users create a contact record via profile

Tags: profile, error

I have a site that allows a visitor to create a contact record, by filling in a form.  However whenever these forms are used they alaways generate an error 500.  No matter which of the several profiles are used, (does not matter i they are inline or not), you get the following error:

```
[Wed Jul 11 18:42:29.819744 2018] [:error] [pid 26665] [client 51.52.150.202:52376] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_strtoupper() in ...../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/html2text/rcube_html2text.php:705\nStack trace:\n#0 ...../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/html2text/rcube_html2text.php(687): rcube_html2text->_strtoupper('\\t\\t        Volun...')\n#1 ...../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/html2text/rcube_html2text.php(652): rcube_html2text->_toupper('\\t\\t        Volun...')\n#2 [internal function]: rcube_html2text->tags_preg_callback(Array)\n#3 ...../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/html2text/rcube_html2text.php(472): preg_replace_callback(Array, Array, '<!DOCTYPE html ...')\n#4 ...../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/html2text/rcube_html2text.php(436): rcube_html2text->_converter('<!DOCTYPE html ...')\n#5 ...../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/html2text/rcube_html2text.php(376): rcube_html2text->_convert()\n in ...../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/html2text/rcube_html2text.php on line 705, referer: .....
```

This occurrs on CiviCRM 5.3.0 used on Wordpress

Comment: Could you please verify if _mbstring_ is enabled on your server You can get more details about installation here: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Comment: Hi, That appeared to fix it, odd though as there were no errors during install.